# Domino Anonymous submit form, but lookup values for radio buttons

Tags: lotus-domino

In a traditional Domino database, I am trying to provide a web form for Anonymous entities to submit, and the submit button that is displayed runs an agent I signed (I have full admin rights) but some of the fields on the form need flexible choices driven by other config documents.    I have Anonymous set in ACL as depositor but with "read public documents" and "write public documents" privileges.  The config docs use a form that has the "Available to public access users"...so I thought this would work, but the choices in the form if I am not logged in are blank...but are all there if I log in.

What am I missing to get this "public access" thing to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The config docs also need a field "$PublicAccess" set to "1" to be readable for public access users.

Comment: I don't know if the Help section mentions this but it would really be good if HCL put up some kind of checklist to enable this scenario.   Thank you Oliver this worked like a charm!

Comment: The Help page does mention this. In fact, it's a checklist. :-) 

https://help.hcltechsw.com/dom_designer/10.0.1/basic/H_ABOUT_CREATING_FORMS_AND_VIEWS_FOR_PUBLIC_ACCESS.html